# How to write/convert multi-line JavaScript code in Typescript callback?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this callback(subscribe) which gets executed when the response for the ajax call has been completed.

```
this.workerService.isLogin()
  .subscribe(res => this.isLoginSuccess = res; 
             console.log(this.isLoginSuccess); 
             this.router.navigateByUrl('/employees');
  );
```

It typescript, it is equivalent to:

```
(function (res) { return _this.isLoginSuccess = res; });
console.log(this.isLoginSuccess);
this.router.navigateByUrl('/employees');
```

I want the transpilation to be:

```
(function (res) { 

    return _this.isLoginSuccess = res; 
    console.log(this.isLoginSuccess);
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/employees');

});
```

I am new to Typescript.

Comment: This *really* should have thrown a syntax error instead of transpiling to anything.

Comment: @Bergi: Noted. Learning things ::))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a block there:

```
this.workerService.isLogin()
  .subscribe(res => {
      this.isLoginSuccess = res; 
      console.log(this.isLoginSuccess); 
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/employees');
  });
```

Comment: One more thing. I see that the block gets executed only when res is true(returned from server). How can I handle the case when res is other than true?

Comment: That’s up to the implementation of `isLogin` when to emit an event.